# How to generate PS1 in a function (escaping issues)

Tags: bash, colors, escaping, command-prompt, ps1

I'd like to move my bash prompt's construction into a function that can build it up modularly. The problem is that I cannot figure out how to get the function's result to be interpreted.

Example:

```
function build_prompt {
  echo "\@"
}
export PS1="\$(build_prompt)"
```

My prompt always shows as `\@`, but should be the current time.

Sure there are ways around this particular example, but I'd like a general solution so I can use it for other escaped components, such as colours.

Comment: Why not just set and export PS1 from the function?

Comment: Because the components in the prompt may change each time it is displayed (e.g. display segment about git if I am in a git repo, but not otherwise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one use case for the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable: running a function just before displaying the prompt that updates the value of `PS1`.

```
function build_prompt {
    PS1='\@'
}
PROMPT_COMMAND='build_prompt'
```